# Does anyone know how to access the username and password from the Login Config Element in jMeter inside of a BeanShell?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Does anyone know how to access the username and password from the Login Config Element in jMeter inside of a BeanShell?

I am trying to access the Login Config Element from and HTTPRequest also.  I need to have the password saved with the dot overlay so that it is secure for my companies use.  I want to access them from an HTTPRequest so that I don't have to put the username and password in cleartext.  Then I want to access it in a BeanShell Post script so that I can change the password before the Simple Data Writer writes the HTTP request output to a file.

Thus far I have been unable to find any useful information on how to do this.

I have tried this script so far which does replace the password written in the Simple Data Listener file but I still have to put it in clear text and I would prefer to put a variable or use a function to access the variable.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampleResult;
import java.lang.String;

prev.setHTTPMethod(prev.getHTTPMethod().replace("password","*********"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Jmeter API](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/api/index.html) to see if it lists how the username/password are being stored? (it may not)

If the API can't help you, you may be able to do a debug sampler and see if the username/password are being stored as variables/properties.

Beanshell samplers can access both variables and properties.